# How to generate the Certificate Chain for AWS load balancer?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I'm using Amazon Load Balancer with SSL configuration. everything when fine except on Firefox that show the exception page. It looks not self to user.

This [article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/15/setting-up-ssl-on-an-amazon-elastic-load-balancer/) suggest to put the Certificate Chain to the configuration section.

[image]

My SSL provider is Comodo (InstantSSL). They provide two files .crt and .ca-bundle only.

How can i generate the Certificate Chain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cat the .crt and the .ca-bundle file together. That's what we wound up doing using a service called OpDemand, which is backed by AWS.

`cat certfile.crt bundle.ca-bundle >> chain.crt`

chain.crt should be the file you're looking for. Also, the order is important. The certificate.crt file has to be first.

Comment: Would you tell me the location of those files

Comment: These files will be provided to you by the certificate issuer.

Answer (score 3):

Use Root.crt and Intermediate.crt content and arrange them in following order. you can create this file manually as well

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
     <Root content>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    <Intermediate content>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

[More Information](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=192570)

Comment: See [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains-prerequisites.html) - Point 2.e.

If you are using root certificate, you have to end it with root certificate, seems like sequence is important for the chain information.

Answer (score 0):

Comodo should provide you with the Certificate Chain. This is not something that you can generate yourself. A quick google looks like you should be able to download it from here: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=1

Comment: Comodo provides you with intermediarie(s) and root certs. separated, at least you have to chain them, with 'cat' f..i.