# Using Comodo SSL with AWS Certificate Chain

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, certificate, load-balancing, chain

This is basically a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044451/how-to-generate-the-certificate-chain-for-aws-load-balancer). After buying a Comodo SSL Certificate, I was also only sent two files in a zip folder - fake_domain.crt and fake_domain.ca-bundle. Most references I have seen say that I should have received 4 files, such as COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt.

To upload my SSL cert onto the AWS load balancer, it requires the Private Key, Public Key Certificate and Certificate Chain, all in PEM format. The private key and cert are simple enough. For the chain, using the answer from the referred question -

```
cat certfile.crt bundle.ca-bundle >> chain.crt
```

did not work. AWS responded with the following error:

Error creating certificate
Unable to validate certificate chain. The certificate chain must start with the immediate signing certificate, followed by any intermediaries in order. The index within the chain of the invalid certificate is: 1

Converting both of the files to PEM format and THEN concatenating also failed. This was the command I used and then copied the output into AWS Certificate Chain field:

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in fake_domain.crt; openssl x509 -inform PEM -in fake_domain.ca-bundle
```

How do I create the Certificate Chain correctly for AWS load balancers?

Comment: How many certs are in the bundle file?  If 2 or more of them, then $5 says they are assembled in reverse order.  If you're willing to take a leap of faith, reverse the order of the cert blocks in the bundle with a text editor and try again, and if it works, I'll explain how that can be divined from the file contents; if it doesn't work, the same explanation should help you sort it out.

Comment: It is a single SSL cert for a wildcard domain. If I reverse the order within the bundle file, I will still have to convert that file to PEM for AWS, right? And if it is incorrect, that shouldn't cause any problems I would think...

Comment: The ordering is critical.  Remember, it's a "chain" of trust.  Your cert has your site as the subject, and has an issuer; the first cert in the chain has that issuer as the subject, and a different issuer; the next in the chain has the prior issuer as subject, down the line until a CA is encountered that's in the trust store.  In reverse order, the "chain" is broken, hence *The index within the chain of the invalid certificate is: 1*. Also, I would have expected the certs to already be in PEM format.  I don't recall needing to convert them.

Comment: re: *"how many certs are in the bundle file?"* ... how many "blocks" are in the file was the question, there.  It's those blocks I'm suggesting need to be reversed.  If 3, change 1,2,3 to 3,2,1.  Don't concatenate with your cert, since AWS provides a separate space for your cert.

Comment: Thank you @Michael for your help

Comment: Was that it? The file was upside down?

Comment: Actually it turns out that the research I was looking at was overcomplicating things. A direct copy paste of all values without attempting to convert to PEM worked just fine.

Comment: D'oh.  Or that, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Certificate Chain is determined by certificate type that you buy. If you buy ssl certificate from Comodo they will send .crt and .key files which are Certificate body and Certificate Private Key.

Certificate Chain is not related with that file. You can take certificate chain file from Comodo for your ssl type. For example, if you buy ositiveSSL / EssentialSSL SHA-256 from Comodo, you need to verify your certificate with certificate chain below:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGCDCCA/CgAwIBAgIQKy5u6tl1NmwUim7bo3yMBzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADCB
hTELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G
A1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09NT0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxKzApBgNV
BAMTIkNPTU9ETyBSU0EgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwHhcNMTQwMjEy
MDAwMDAwWhcNMjkwMjExMjM1OTU5WjCBkDELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgT
EkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMR
Q09NT0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxNjA0BgNVBAMTLUNPTU9ETyBSU0EgRG9tYWluIFZh
bGlkYXRpb24gU2VjdXJlIFNlcnZlciBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEP
ADCCAQoCggEBAI7CAhnhoFmk6zg1jSz9AdDTScBkxwtiBUUWOqigwAwCfx3M28Sh
bXcDow+G+eMGnD4LgYqbSRutA776S9uMIO3Vzl5ljj4Nr0zCsLdFXlIvNN5IJGS0
Qa4Al/e+Z96e0HqnU4A7fK31llVvl0cKfIWLIpeNs4TgllfQcBhglo/uLQeTnaG6
ytHNe+nEKpooIZFNb5JPJaXyejXdJtxGpdCsWTWM/06RQ1A/WZMebFEh7lgUq/51
UHg+TLAchhP6a5i84DuUHoVS3AOTJBhuyydRReZw3iVDpA3hSqXttn7IzW3uLh0n
c13cRTCAquOyQQuvvUSH2rnlG51/ruWFgqUCAwEAAaOCAWUwggFhMB8GA1UdIwQY
MBaAFLuvfgI9+qbxPISOre44mOzZMjLUMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSQr2o6lFoL2JDqElZz
30O0Oija5zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwEgYDVR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAdBgNV
HSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwGwYDVR0gBBQwEjAGBgRVHSAAMAgG
BmeBDAECATBMBgNVHR8ERTBDMEGgP6A9hjtodHRwOi8vY3JsLmNvbW9kb2NhLmNv
bS9DT01PRE9SU0FDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uQXV0aG9yaXR5LmNybDBxBggrBgEFBQcB
AQRlMGMwOwYIKwYBBQUHMAKGL2h0dHA6Ly9jcnQuY29tb2RvY2EuY29tL0NPTU9E
T1JTQUFkZFRydXN0Q0EuY3J0MCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5jb21v
ZG9jYS5jb20wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEMBQADggIBAE4rdk+SHGI2ibp3wScF9BzWRJ2p
mj6q1WZmAT7qSeaiNbz69t2Vjpk1mA42GHWx3d1Qcnyu3HeIzg/3kCDKo2cuH1Z/
e+FE6kKVxF0NAVBGFfKBiVlsit2M8RKhjTpCipj4SzR7JzsItG8kO3KdY3RYPBps
P0/HEZrIqPW1N+8QRcZs2eBelSaz662jue5/DJpmNXMyYE7l3YphLG5SEXdoltMY
dVEVABt0iN3hxzgEQyjpFv3ZBdRdRydg1vs4O2xyopT4Qhrf7W8GjEXCBgCq5Ojc
2bXhc3js9iPc0d1sjhqPpepUfJa3w/5Vjo1JXvxku88+vZbrac2/4EjxYoIQ5QxG
V/Iz2tDIY+3GH5QFlkoakdH368+PUq4NCNk+qKBR6cGHdNXJ93SrLlP7u3r7l+L4
HyaPs9Kg4DdbKDsx5Q5XLVq4rXmsXiBmGqW5prU5wfWYQ//u+aen/e7KJD2AFsQX
j4rBYKEMrltDR5FL1ZoXX/nUh8HCjLfn4g8wGTeGrODcQgPmlKidrv0PJFGUzpII
0fxQ8ANAe4hZ7Q7drNJ3gjTcBpUC2JD5Leo31Rpg0Gcg19hCC0Wvgmje3WYkN5Ap
lBlGGSW4gNfL1IYoakRwJiNiqZ+Gb7+6kHDSVneFeO/qJakXzlByjAA6quPbYzSf
+AZxAeKCINT+b72x
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I've copied it from https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/comodo-positivessl-essentialssl-sha-2-ca-bundle. You can find appropriate **certificate chain** for your ssl certificate.